# Expressing the power series as a function

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I want to express the following power series

$$1+x+x^2+3x^3+x^4+5x^5+x^6+7x^7+x^8+..$$
As a function
For this purpose, I started from the following
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$
from where

$f'(x)=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4+..$

$xf''(x)=1+2x^2+3x^3+4x^4+5x^5+..$

It seems that the expression is becoming similar to the one I have in the statement, however I don't know how else to proceed, any suggestions? thanks

Comment: why dont you subtract $\sum x^n$ and then integrate the result ?

Comment: Also note that you can split the series into $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty (2n+1)x^{2n+1}.$$
With some manipulation, you should be able to get your result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your series is the sum of$$1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\cdots=\frac1{1-x^2}$$with\begin{align}x+3x^3+5x^5+\cdots&=x\left(1+3x^2+5x^4+\cdots\right)\\&=x\left(x+x^3+x^5+\cdots\right)'\\&=x\left(\frac x{1-x^2}\right)'\\&=\frac{x^3+x}{\left(x^2-1\right)^2},\end{align}and therefore the sum of your series is$$\frac1{1-x^2}+\frac{x^3+x}{\left(x^2-1\right)^2}=\frac{x^3-x^2+x+1}{\left(x^2-1\right)^2}.$$

Comment: @RaadShaikh I've edited my answer. Thank you.